# CloudFormation retain resource based upon non-presence of list value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I pass a list of active profile names to my CloudFormation template as a list:

```yaml
  Profiles:
    Description: The comma-separated list of active profiles, such as "dev,test".
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
```

I have a resource I want to retain if I'm not running in a `dev` environment, i.e. if `"dev"` is not one of the strings in the `Profiles` list. Here is some pseudocode for what I'm looking for:

```yaml
  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    # pseudocode
    DeletionPolicy: Profiles.contains("dev") ? Delete : Retain
    # hypothetical syntax
    DeletionPolicy: !Contains [!Ref Profiles, "dev", Delete, Retain]
```

Does CloudFormation allow me to create a conditional deletion policy based upon whether a string is in a parameter list?

Comment: Yes, it does. I recommend you read this doc on cloudformation conditionals:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if

See example 3

Comment: Right; I looked through that document, but I can't readily find the condition function for "is present in list". I see the `Fn::Equals` in the [sample template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html), but there the environment is a single value, not a list. As explained in the question, I want to check if a value is present in a list of value supplied as a parameter. @matheusopedro could you point me to the condition function I should be looking at?

Comment: So @Paolo your answer is basically "no, it can't be done"; did I understand correctly?

Comment: @GarretWilson that's correct

Answer (score 1):

> Does CloudFormation allow me to create a conditional deletion policy based upon whether a string is in a parameter list?

Unfortunately not. There is a `Fn::Contains` function however this may only be used in a CloudFormation Rule:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-rules.html